# Email Audience Entry - Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I've been trying to move my new triggers onto Journey Builder (all of them were through a query+automation studio.

I've created new data extension for 3 new pathways but when selecting the Email Audience Entry for it and after activation, it tells me Automation paused at the bottom of the Audience setting. Except I didn't set it from an Automation but from Email Audience which is a Sendable Data Extension not an Automation from Automation Studio. What am I missing for it to populate my pathway with the population from my Data Extension?

[image: Seen from my pathway]

After I clicked on the event results, there's 46 contacts to be evaluated but none of them makes it into my pathway. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schedule you set will evaluate entries on 22nd June at 12:00 AM and daily after that (as can be seen in your first screenshot). So on the "Next Run" there will be 46 Contacts evaluated for journey entry (as can be seen in your second screenshot).

Additionally, if you click on "PAUSED" and then confirm you want to leave journey builder, you will see the Automation that is created in the background is set to "Active" and the schedule is displayed. After that, go back to journey builder and you will see the Automation is "Running" (maybe even a hard-reload in journey builder will help as it might only be a display bug).

*Further reading / related documentation:*

- [Create an Email Studio Audience](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/journey_builder_audiences/create_an_email_studio_audience/)

Comment: Oooh yeah, makes sense for the Next Run I was too fixed on the "PAUSED" Automation Status to think about it. I'm still getting my "PAUSED" Automation Status on my JB pathway even if the Automationis set to "Active" so might be a display bug. Thanks for the answer! :)